# Laravel Create item with value from dropdown list

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a laravel application. In my database i have 2 table's called: 'folder' and 'subfolder' folder is basically the parent of subfolder.
I almost have a working crud, except for create and edit subfolders.
To create a subfolder i also have to give a folder_id value. but this needs to be a dropdown with the name's of the folders. i kind of got it working, it only duplicate the value of the folder name multiple times according to the amount of subfolders i have
[image].

but it only has to show 1 time 'product documentatie' instead of three times as you can see on the image

subfolder.create:

```
  <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Folder</label>
          <select name="folder_id" class="form-control">
          @foreach($subfolders as $subfolder)
          <option value=" {{$subfolder->folder->name}}">{{$subfolder->folder->name}}</option>
          @endforeach
          </select>
        </div>
```

subfolder controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Subfolder;

class SubfolderController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $subfolders = Subfolder::with('folder')->get();

        return view('admin.subfolder.index', compact('subfolders'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
            
           ]);
    
           $subfolder = new Subfolder([
            'name'=> $request->get('name'),
           ]);
           $subfolder->save();
           return back();
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $subfolders = Subfolder::all();
        $subfolderEdit = Subfolder::find($id);
        return view('admin.subfolder.index', compact('subfolderEdit', 'subfolders'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
            'folder_id'=>'required',
        ]);

        $subfolderData = [
         'name' => $request->name,
         'folder_id' => $request->folder_id,
        ];

        Subfolder::whereId($id)->update($subfolderData);
        return redirect()->route('admin.subfolder.index');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $subfolder = Subfolder::find($id);
        $subfolder->delete();
        return redirect()->route('admin.subfolder.index');
    }
}
```

if i need to add any imformation i will gladly provide it!

Comment: Can you please provide your controller code?

Comment: In list items you can only show folders querying from Folder Table, or Distinct duplicates items from subfolder results. When you want to create a subfolder, I guess first one is good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically when you do `$subfolders = Subfolder::with('folder')->get();` you are getting all folders but you get duplicates. For example if a folder has 3 subfolders, you will retrieve it 3 times.

You could group the result by folder ID.

Something like

`$subfolders = Subfolder::with('folder')->groupBy('folderId')->get();`

could work (assuming the folder ID is `'folderId'`)

You can check [Laravel official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#grouping) to find out more about grouping.